# Some quadratic form on four dimensional symplectic space

Tags: linear-algebra, isotropic-submanifolds

Let $V$ be a four dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space with standard symplectic form. Is there a nondegenerate quadratic form on $V$, whose maximal isotropic spaces are also maximal isotropic spaces of the symplectic structure? I want an explicit construction.